# offline web application using JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, ria, offlineapps

HTML5 does support offline web application.I want to create an offline web application using JavaFX. Does anyone has an example related to the same?

Comment: Do you want to run an offline JavaFX application? Or do you want JavaFX to run HTML5 offline web pages?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of javaFX mentions how you can do this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm#CJACGDDE

First learn a bit about how packaging and deployment works.
Then you know how to work with the examples.

You can find tutorials that include examples with code here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/index.html
(Take a look at the Packaging and Deployment in the Deployment and More section.)